# How to add focus on the cancel label of the popup?

Tags: angularjs

I have this popup function. It has a template for the pop up. Has one delete and cancel button. I want to have focus on the cancel button when the popup opens. How can i do that?

```
$scope.Popup = function(funcname){
  alert_template({
            id: '',
            title: '',
            scope: $scope,
           template: '<div class=""><span>Delete the selected item?</span></div>',
            success: {
                    label: 'Delete',
                    fn: function(){
                        //Do Something
                        }
                },
                cancel: {
                    label: 'Cancel',
                    fn: //Do Something

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Versions of JS differ you may or not need the # to identify the object.

JavaScript:

`document.getElementById('cancel').focus();`

jQuery:

`$('#cancel').focus();`

Comment: do i write this condition in the popup function or inside the alert_template ; cancel button only has label no id.

Comment: It would make the most sense putting it at the end of your main function. The button needs to render before focus will work.